# Most Pythonic way of setting user-friendly and explicit flag values?

Tags: python, oop, flags

What's the most Pythonic way of giving flags values that are user-friendly and self-evident for whoever is reading the code?

Assume I got the following method for a class, which depending on the input will calculate a certain `multiplier` and set a `cracking_mode` flag for that class instance:

```
def evaluate_first_matrix_crack(self, base_sigma22, base_tau12):
    # Mixed transverse tension-shear
    if base_sigma22 > 0 and base_tau12 != 0:
       self.cracking_mode = 2
       multiplier = sqrt(1. / ((base_sigma22 / self.Yt_is) ** 2 + (base_tau12 / self.S_is) ** 2))

    # Pure transverse tension
    elif base_sigma22 > 0 and base_tau12 == 0:
        self.cracking_mode = 0
        multiplier = self.Yt_is / base_sigma22

    # Pure shear
    elif base_sigma22 <= 0 and base_tau12 != 0:
       self.cracking_mode = 1
        multiplier = self.Yt_is / base_sigma22

    return multiplier
```

The "cracking_mode" flag will affect which methods are called in other sections of the code. I want the flag values to be as user-friendly as possible, so that when they are checked through if statements in other sections of the code, the reader can immediately tell which flag value corresponds to which option.

**So rather than having `self.cracking_mode = 2` I would ideally have `self.cracking_mode = "mixed_transverse_tension_shear"`.**

**However, I don't think that's a Pythonic way of doing things, aside from the fact that comparing strings takes longer than comparing integers.**

So what would be the most Pythonic (and user-friendly) way of solving the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of `enum` in other languages. In my opinion, the most "pythonic" way to do things is simply the clearest - so string comparison isn't that bad. Probably a little better would be to create constants that represent the values (`MIXED_TRANVERSE_TENSION_SHEAR = 2`) as static class members, and then compare to those constants, which is a more efficent integer comparison.

Comment: The static class member idea is pretty neat! I will make sure to try it out, thanks!